# How long would it take for magnets to deplete their energy, if I were to propel a ball through a magnetic loop?

Tags: electromagnetism

I saw a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdoLXChlJ_4), where a guy was able to propel a ball using magnets.

Suppose I designed a circular magnetic accelerator, and I was able to propel the ball until the energy in the magnets depletes.

- How long would it take for the magnets to deplete their energy?
- Is this possible, can I really develop a loop that will propel a ball
  until the magnets die? **(Without hooking it up to an electrical source of energy)**

Comment: There's a lot wrong with your understanding of magnetism (including, that magnetic forces on their own can perform work based on some internal stored energy than can be depleted). My best recommendation is, if you are interested, to find a good source to learn introductory electromagnetism at the level you are interested in.

Comment: @jwimberley Thank you, I was suspecting that something was wrong. Otherwise, we would've exploited magnets as a renewable source of energy.

Comment: Yeah, that's generally a good line of reasoning for things like this. A simple rule to keep in mind is that magnets bend things' paths, but don't propel them -- aforementioned EM introductions would go into the theory behind that.